# utf-8 post to php page - values not as expected

Tags: php, post, http-post

Not even quite sure how to ask this as I do not understand what exactly is happening.  This is a license generator script which is posted to my php page.  The values are being posted to me in utf-8 format and they allow strange characters for the name field.

Name sent to me - Вагиф Сәмәдоғлу

It's value in the posted url - &name=%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%84+%D0%A1%D3%99%D0%BC%D3%99%D0%B4%D0%BE%D2%93%D0%BB%D1%83

Now on my side I run some code on the name :

```
//strip name of everything but chars and digits
$cust_name = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $_POST['name']);

//use first 10 characters (if there is)
$cust_name = strtolower( substr( $cust_name, 0, 10) );      

//pad random characters to username until it is unique in the database
do {
    //random 30 character string            
    $random = substr(md5(microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,30);

    //pad username with random string to ensure it is 20 chars long
    $account_username = str_pad($cust_name, 20 , $random);
} while ( !usernameAvail($db, $account_username) );
```

Problem is the result of $account_username is e2201b0ef6eb463213f6

Now, if the posted name is a 'normal' name such as 'Joe Schmoe' then there are no problems at all :

Name sent to me - Joe Schmoe

It's value in the posted url - &name=Joe+Schmoe

$account_username is joeschmoe6eb463213f6

Comment: My guess is that the name isn't comming trough clear.. Because the username is only the random generated string.. And you normally take 10 from name and 10 from random.. But since name is empty you only get random?

Comment: I honestly have no idea... if I save my posted variables to file and view the file in utf-8 the value is exactly Вагиф Сәмәдоғлу as it should be.  The result though after my code does not show this, but works correctly when given a 'normal' name.

Comment: You do know it's a url encoded string right ? @Naruto is right.since you are replacing any non word chars with empty strings `$cust_name` gets an empty value and then `str_pad` function pad it with 20 random chars.

Comment: Yes, I know it is url encoded, but when it is received on my end it is auto decoded if that makes sense.  Thinking it through more that has nothing to do with it - it is my stripping of all non-word characters which is causing this as each one of those is a non-word char.  So... it is working just as it should.  Unfortunately I cannot control the validation coming to me to prevent those characters being used in a name.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) instead of all this stuff. In any case, you will not be able to stock cyrillic alphabet in your database if it is not made for (even french or spanish). You can first check the encoding and use something like [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) :

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)
```